# Executing Azure Stored Procedure from Azure Triggering Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I wrote a  stored procedure for deleting records from cosmosDB based on updation date of the document.
The cosmosDB collection is having large number (say 500) of partition keys so that I have to execute the stored procedure 500 times.
I am trying to execute an azure stored procedure from Azure time triggering function.

Below are the codes written in azure triggering function:

Added new file project.json

```js
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB": "2.0.0"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

run.csx fle is updated as below.

```cs
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"

    using System;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;

    public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer,  IEnumerable<dynamic> 
    inputDocument, TraceWriter log)
    {
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function started at: {DateTime.Now}");

    // Get the date 6 months before from Current Time in IST and convert to Epoch value. 
    TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India 
    Standard Time");
    DateTime indianTime =  
    TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-180), 
    INDIAN_ZONE);


    long epochTime = (long)(indianTime - new DateTime(1970, 1, 
    1)).TotalSeconds;

    DocumentClient client;
    string endpoint = "https://***cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/";
    string key = "****";
    client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), key);

    foreach (var doc in inputDocument)
        {
            string partKey = doc.NUM;
            StoredProcedureResponse<bool> sprocResponse = await 
    client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<bool>(

   "/dbs/DB_NAME/colls/COLLECTION_NAME/sprocs/STORED PROC_NAME/",new 
    RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partKey) });

            log.Info($"Cosmos DB is updated at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
```

I am getting the below error while compiling the above code.

```
2019-08-22T15:30:01.759 [Error] Exception while executing function: Functions.TimerTriggerCSharp1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more errors occurred. Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client: Failed to deserialize stored procedure response or convert it to type 'System.Boolean': Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1. Newtonsoft.Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.
2019-08-22T15:30:01.822 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=02da4d71-8207-4227-9c79-1cc277439c20, Duration=1814ms)
```

I have to pass a date parameter and array of partition keys while executing the stored procedure. 
I am totally stuck in this stage. what could be done to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Portal, you need to pull in the dependency at the top of your Function like so:

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
```

And please, use a newer version of the SDK, 1.7.1 is from more than 3 years ago: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB/

Comment: I was using Azure function2.x which I have changed to 1.x now. Now I am getting another error `{"Errors":["Owner resource does not exist"]}` while running the function. Updated the code and error. Could you please check the parameters which I have passed to execute the stored procedure?

Comment: Owner resource does not exist means that either the Database, or the Collection (or both) do not exist.

Comment: "/dbs/DB_NAME/colls/COLLECTION_NAME/sprocs/STORED PROC_NAME/" needs to be a real path, where DB_NAME needs to be your real database name, COLLECTION_NAME your real collection name, and STORED PROC_NAME your real sproc name.

Comment: Thank You @Matias Quaranta: That error got resolved,  have to pass a parameter (**epochTime**  in code) to stored procedure. How to pass that from the existing code ?

Comment: Pass it as the last parameter on the ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync call, see the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.executestoredprocedureasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync__1_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_System_Object___

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Matias Quaranta. This works fine now. Able to trigger SP from time triggered azure function.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that your script code of your Azure Function is not correct.

Remove all `private` and `static` declarations inside your function.

```cs
private static DocumentClient client;
static string endpoint;
static string key
```

==>

```cs
DocumentClient client;
string endpoint;
string key;
```

General advise: Do not author Functions in the Azure portal (in .csx). Do yourself a favor and use a proper IDE such as VS Code.

Comment: I made the above mentioned changes, but still I am getting same error!

Comment: the very same error? Or are there more syntax errors in the script that I didnt catch?

Comment: See, that is a very different error. It is probably missing the reference to the `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client` nuget package. Again, please do yourself a favor and write your function in VS Code. All those issues that you faced here will go away. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-vs-code